# Picture menu - make current page stand out

Tags: html, css, image, colors, menu

I want the menu on our website to clearly show what page you're on.
The menu consists of 6 pictures, whose brightness I let increase on mouse hover.
I also make the pictures smaller for mobile phones, depending on screen width.

I would like the 5 other pictures in the menu to be black and white, or less saturated than the current page you're on.

Is this possible? I saw a post using the list function, for text menus, but I was not succesfull making it work.

Picture of menu FYI
[image: screenshot]

The code I am using is as follows:

```css
@media (max-width:629px) {
  img#optionalstuff {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width:630px) {
  img#mobilestuff {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
 .image5 {
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
transition: all 0.7s ease;
} 
    
.image5:hover {
-webkit-filter: brightness(1.17);

}

</style>

<div class="uk-grid-column-small uk-grid-column-collapse uk-child-width-1-6@m uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
    <div>
        <div ><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/vacuum-koeler-voor-brood-bakkerij"><img class="image5" id="optionalstuff" src="https://iili.io/HgqonS.png" alt="Brood & Bakkerij vacuum cooling" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
  <div ><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/vacuum-koeler-voor-brood-bakkerij"><img class="image5" id="mobilestuff" src="https://webercooling.com/images/Carrouselmenu/NL/mob_broodbakkerij.png" alt="Brood & Bakkerij vacuum cooling" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/industriele-koeltechniek-voor-de-professionele-keuken"><img class="image5" id="optionalstuff" img src="https://iili.io/HUmKyF.png" alt="Koeltechniek voor de keuken" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
  <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/industriele-koeltechniek-voor-de-professionele-keuken"><img class="image5" id="mobilestuff" img src="https://webercooling.com/images/Carrouselmenu/NL/mob_voedselkeuken.png" alt="Koeltechniek voor de keuken" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
 </div>
    <div>
        <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/vacuum-koeler-voor-sushi-rijst"><img class="image5" id="optionalstuff" img src="https://iili.io/HUmFv1.png" alt="Vacuum cooler voor rijst" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
  <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/vacuum-koeler-voor-sushi-rijst"><img class="image5" id="mobilestuff" img src="https://webercooling.com/images/Carrouselmenu/NL/mob_sushirijst.png" alt="Vacuum cooler voor rijst" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
 </div>
    <div>
        <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/vacuum-koeler-voor-groenten-en-kruiden"><img class="image5" id="optionalstuff" img src="https://iili.io/Hg93a2.png" alt="Groenten en kruiden vacuum cooling" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
  <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/vacuum-koeler-voor-groenten-en-kruiden"><img class="image5" id="mobilestuff" img src="https://webercooling.com/images/Carrouselmenu/NL/mob_groentenkruiden.png" alt="Groenten en kruiden vacuum cooling" height="652" width="668"></a></div>    
 </div>
    <div>
        <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/cold-chain-management-voor-bloemen"><img class="image5" id="optionalstuff" img src="https://iili.io/Hg9J44.png" alt="Bloemen en koudeketen" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
  <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/cold-chain-management-voor-bloemen"><img class="image5" id="mobilestuff" img src="https://webercooling.com/images/Carrouselmenu/NL/mob_bloemenkoudeketen.png" alt="Bloemen en koudeketen" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
 </div>
    <div>
        <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/vacuum-koeler-voor-turf-compost"><img class="image5" id="optionalstuff" img src="https://iili.io/HgdDlf.png" alt="Turf en compost koeling" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
  <div><a href="https://webercooling.com/nl/vacuum-koeler-voor-turf-compost"><img class="image5" id="mobilestuff" img src="https://webercooling.com/images/Carrouselmenu/NL/mob_grascompost.png" alt="Turf en compost koeling" height="652" width="668"></a></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Kind regards,
Joey

Comment: Seems like some kind of  home work

Comment: For most this might be easy, but for me this is something I never tried to achieve before :)

Answer (score 0):

`
a img{
 -webkit-filter: brightness(50%)
}

a:active img, a:visited img{
   -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
}`

Comment: Hi Madi,
Thank you so much for your reply! Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work properly and I do not see any changes. Above you find the whole code, I changed the above part to:
<style>
 .image5 {
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
transition: all 0.7s ease;
} 
    
.image5:hover {
-webkit-filter: brightness(1.17);

}

    ` a img{ -webkit-filter: brightness(50%) }

a:active img, a:visited img{ -webkit-filter: brightness(1); }`
    
</style>